# Render partial with locals and html tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a partial which I'm rendering in my view. I'm using two locals: icon and path.

The issue I'm encountering is that I don't know how to pass the following parameters:

```
"About", "https://www.google.com", target: "_blank", class: "medium button radius", id: "about_us"
```

to the path local.

Any help/tips, greatly appreciated.

**Code without locals**

_footer.html.erb

```
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">

        <div class="footer-icon">
          <span><%= fa_icon “home” %></span>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-button">
          <%= link_to "About", "https://www.google.com",
          target: "_blank", class: "medium button radius",
          id: "about_us" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

about.html.erb

```
<% content_for :footer_class do %>
  <% render partial: 'layouts/footer',  %>
<% end %>
```

**Code with locals**

_footer.html.erb

```
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">

        <div class="footer-icon">
          <span><%= fa_icon icon %></span>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-button">
          <%= link_to path %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

about.html.erb

```
<% content_for :footer_class do %>
  <% render partial: 'layouts/footer', locals: {icon: "home", path: ? } %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a hash and access the values in the view:

about.html.erb

```
<% path_hash = {
  label: "About",
  destinatoin: "https://www.google.com",
  target: "_blank",
  class: "medium button radius",
  id: "about_us" 
} %>
<% content_for :footer_class do %>
  <% render partial: 'layouts/footer', locals: {icon: "home", path_attrs: path_hash } %>
<% end %>
```

Then in _footer.html.erb

```
<div class="footer-button">
  <%= link_to path_attrs[:label], path_attrs[:destination], target: path_attrs[:target], id: path_attrs[:id], class: path_attrs[:class]  %>
</div>
```

Not sure why you're doing it this way in the first place. Seems like it could get messy over time, but this should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks. Everything works great, except the link to google. Any reason why this might be? This is the html that is generated: `<a class="medium button radius" href="/about" id="contact_button">contact</a>` I removed target for this example. The reason I'm doing this is because I have three different footers and the only differences between them is the icon and link. Right now I have three different partials for the footers, so it's just repetitive code. I'm a newbie, so happy to hear other suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Not sure why the href attribute isn't working. I edited the answer right after I posted it, so if you take a look at it after this comment is posted it should be working fine.

Comment: I figured out the issue after a few hours. I copied and pasted your code so I wouldn't make any errors, but 'destination' is misspelled in your code so that's why the href didn't work. There's also a comma missing after "About". Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry about the typos. I fixed them in case this answer is useful for someone else. Glad it worked.